# Testing Spring web services end point at server side?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using Spring WS 2.0 . I have seen below end point and and test case to test the end point.

```
@Endpoint                                                                                
public class CustomerEndpoint {

  @ResponsePayload                                                                       
  public CustomerCountResponse getCustomerCount(                                         
      @RequestPayload CustomerCountRequest request) {                                    
    CustomerCountResponse response = new CustomerCountResponse();
    response.setCustomerCount(10);
    return response;
  }
}
```

---

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.xml.transform.StringSource;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient;                          
import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.RequestCreators.*;                      
import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.ResponseMatchers.*;                     

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)                                                  
@ContextConfiguration("spring-ws-servlet.xml")                                           
public class CustomerEndpointIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;                                         

  private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

  @Before
  public void createClient() {
    mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);                  
  }

  @Test
  public void customerEndpoint() throws Exception {
    Source requestPayload = new StringSource(
      "<customerCountRequest xmlns='http://springframework.org/spring-ws'>" +
        "<customerName>John Doe</customerName>" +
      "</customerCountRequest>");
    Source responsePayload = new StringSource(
      "<customerCountResponse xmlns='http://springframework.org/spring-ws'>" +
        "<customerCount>10</customerCount>" +
      "</customerCountResponse>");

    mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload)).                                 
      andExpect(payload(responsePayload));                                               
  }
}
```

Here I have query regarding the test case. Here we are passing **XML string as request payload**. But in my case i have very large XML file which will have 100 lines. In that case I feel instead of passing XML string **can I pass JAXB generated object (CustomerCountRequest) itself as requestPayload**? How can I do integration test to my end point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Instantiate your CustomerCountRequest object as normal and wrap it in a JAXBSource using a JAXBContext:

```
CustomerCountRequest request = new CustomerCountRequest();
// add setters on the request object if needed
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerCountRequest.class);
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, request);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem these days and i solved like this (i use your object names for request and response):

Note you must have the services up and running

> integration-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/MyServices/ws"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="it.ws.soap" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

> CustomerEndpointIntegrationTest

```
/**
 * Inspired by: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:integration-test.xml")
public class CustomerEndpointIntegrationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @Before
    public void startServer() {
        webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForError(false);
        webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForFault(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() throws Exception {
        CustomerCountRequest request = (CustomerCountRequest) loadRequest("MyRequestBody.xml");
        CustomerCountResponse response = (CustomerCountResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() throws Exception {
        CustomerCountRequest request = (CustomerCountRequest) loadRequest("MyRequestBodyTwo.xml");
        try {
            webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
            Assert.fail();

        } catch (SoapFaultClientException ex) {
            Assert.assertEquals("Validation error", ex.getSoapFault().getFaultStringOrReason());
        }
    }

    private Object loadRequest(String requestName) throws Exception {
        String file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(requestName).getFile();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            return webServiceTemplate.getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(fis));
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are facing similar problem and we solve that reading the xml file from a location accessible from the classpath. At least you don’t have to rewrite the string if you need to change the test case.